# Unity 3D Parse Proxy CONNECT aborted

Tags: performance, exception, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, connection

I have been using the Parse tutorial with Unity 3D in attempt to have the player sign up. I have the initialization behavior set up.

```
var user = new ParseUser()
{
    Username = usernameField.value,
    Password = passwordField.value,
    Email = emailField.value
};

registerTask = user.SignUpAsync();
```

However, when I test this method and call SignUpAsync(), it will attempt to connect to the server and the connection will take a long time (about 10-20 seconds). Afterwords, it would fail and Parse's task would have the following exception. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Proxy CONNECT abortedSystem.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
-----------------
Parse.ParseException: Proxy CONNECT aborted
  at Parse.ParseClient+<>c__DisplayClass8.<RequestAsync>b__7 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1`2[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.String],System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c__DisplayClass3`1+<>c__DisplayClass5[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].<ContinueWith>b__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Calclavia.Artillects.MenuManager:Update() (at Assets/Artillects/Source/Menu/MenuManager.cs:81)
```

Edit:

The specific inner exception prints the following:

```
Error message Proxy CONNECT aborted
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Error code: OtherCause
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

Comment: Can you detail the inner exceptions of the Aggregate exception ?

Comment: `Error message Proxy CONNECT aborted
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Error code: OtherCause
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)`

Comment: Unrelated to parse, I have had a connection aborted when the http request failed. Perhaps the keys are invalid or there is something else blocking communication (a router?).

Have you tried this on another machine. Could you post a sample to google drive (or something) ?